# Call event.preventDefault() after calling event.persist() in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, dom-events

I have researched synthetic events in React and I understand that React pools events to improve performance. I am also aware that events in React are not DOM events. I have read several posts and threads about this topic but I cannot find any mention of calling `preventDefault` after calling `event.persist`.

Many sites have mentioned that if we want to capture the value of `event.target`, for example, that one option is simply to cache it for later use but this does not apply to my use case.

I want to throttle an event handler that is listening for `onDragOver` events. In order to do this in React, I have to pass the event through 3 functions, calling `event.persist` on the first one so that the last one can see it.

However, `event.preventDefault` has no effect when I do call it. It's almost as if once we call `event.persist`, that's it and there's no turning back.

Below is some of the code but you may find it more helpful to experiment with it on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cgeriz?file=README.txt).

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { throttle } from 'throttle-debounce';
import DropItem from './DropItem';

class DropZone extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onDragOverThrottled = throttle(500, this.onDragOver);
    this.onDragStart = this.onDragStart.bind(this);
    this.handleDragOver = this.handleDragOver.bind(this);
  }

  onDragStart(e, id) {
    console.log('dragstart: ', id);
    e.dataTransfer.setData("id", id);
  }

  onDragOver(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  // this does nothing if event.persist fires before it
    console.log('dragover...');
  }

  handleDragOver(e) {
    e.persist();
    this.onDragOverThrottled(e);
  }

  render() {
    const items = this.props.items.map((item, index) => {
      return <DropItem item={item} key={index} onDragStart={this.onDragStart} />;
    });

    return (
      <div
        className={this.props.class}
        //onDragOver={this.handleDragOver}  // See note 1 below
        onDragOver={this.onDragOver}  // See note 2 below
        onDrop={(e) => {this.props.onDrop(e, this.props.location)}}>
        <span className="task-header">{this.props.title}</span>
        {items}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DropZone;

/*

NOTE 1
Commenting in this line shows that throttling works but preventDefault does not and we cannot drag and drop any box to another location.

NOTE 2
This skips throttling altogether but preventDefault does work which allows the box to be moved to a different area. Because throttling is disabled here, onDragOver fires a lot and, at times, keeps the user from moving boxes around quickly.

*/
```

All of the sources I have consulted have effectively implemented either a debounce or throttle to capture a value and then do something with that value but none of them have tried calling `preventDefault` after `persist` as I am attempting to do. Some of these sources are the following:

- Blog [post](https://www.peterbe.com/plog/how-to-throttle-and-debounce-an-autocomplete-input-in-react) on throttling and debouncing
- Example of throttling an input by [peterbe](https://codesandbox.io/s/o7vz8mq6wq)
- A [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c6nLrsty/) that does exactly what I am aiming for but it is not written in React

Comment: You cannot have duplicate prop names.

Comment: @JonasWilms, can you elaborate? I'm unclear what you are referring to.

Comment: `onDragOver={...} onDragOver={...}` won't work. The second one overrides the first. One of the fucntions doesnt even execute.

Comment: Got it. Maybe I wasn't clear but on StackBlitz, you would toggle these to see the difference between an app that works without throttling and an app that implements throttling but doesn't work.

Comment: Well then ... never mind

Answer (score 2):

After further research and experimentation, I found out how to resolve this.

**TL;DR**
My theory that `event.persist()` somehow prevented `event.preventDefault()` from working as expected was incorrect.

**THE REAL PROBLEM**
The reason that my drag-and-drop app did not work with throttling was because `event.persist()` does not forward the event to another handler but simply makes it available for other handlers to access. This means that `event.preventDefault()` must be called on each handler that uses the event. This seems very obvious now that I say it but because I had to send the event through multiple handlers to implement throttling, I mistakenly thought I was passing the event from one to the other.

**DOCUMENTATION**
What I state above is my observation and does not come from React's official documentation. But the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html) do say this:

> If you want to access the event properties in an asynchronous way, you
>   should call `event.persist()` on the event, which will remove the
>   synthetic event from the pool and allow references to the event to be
>   retained by user code.

Although I had read this before, I skipped over it because I did not consider what I was doing to be asynchronous. But the answer is still here– *it allows references to the event to be retained by user code*.

**LEARN MORE**
For those who want to dig into this deeper, be sure to look at the [README](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cgeriz?file=README.txt) in my StackBlitz where I provide further details.

Comment: I believe there is different thing: you are trying to call `event.preventDefault()` in async way, in different event loop cycle(since you use throttling - it's about timeout). If we use `<a href="https://google.com" onclick="const a = event; setTimeout(() => a.preventDefault(), 10)">google</a>` we will see the same result(`preventDefault` does not stop us from navigating away) in old(it's rather HTML4 syntax :) ) vanilla js. not putting that into answer since don't see how to fix your code in appropriate way.